# Java mixed string words, using boolean to check

Tags: java

```
public class Test{                                      
  public static boolean s(String one, String two, String three){                                        
    int[] array = new int[30];                                      
    for (char c : three.toCharArray()) {                                        
      array[c - 97]++;                                      
    }                                       
    for (char c : two.toCharArray()){                                       
      array[c - 97]--;                                      
    }                                       
    for(char c : one.toCharArray()){                                        
      array[c - 97]--;                                      
    }                                       
    for (int value : array){                                        
      if (value > 0){                                       
        return false;                                       
      }                                     
    }                                       
    return true;                                        
  }                                     
}
```

Main

```
public class Main                                       
{                                       
  public static void main(String[] args)                                        
  {                                                                             
    System.out.println(Test.s("test","now","tesntow"));       //true                                                                     
    System.out.println(Test.s("test","here","testhere"));    //false  
    System.out.println(Test.s("test","here","tehstere"));          //true                                                                
    System.out.println(Test.s("test","new","tesntewword"));      //false                                                                                     
  }                                     
}
```

I am trying to return and output where if one or two's value is the same as three, it would return true, else false. However, my output is always true, when it should be true, false, true and false. Is it because it is only checking for same letters in each string so it returns true?

Comment: your code is giving me output : true
true
true
false

Comment: False on the last one? It seems to keep me all true. 
Ahh I wanted it false because it is not a mixed word

Comment: *"if one **or** two's value is the **same** as three"* Then test is simply `three.equals(one) || three.equals(two)`. --- Now, your sample desired output is actually *"if one **and** two  is **not** same as three"*, where "and" means "concatenated with", which is `! three.equals(one + two)`.

Comment: Since you went through the work to write code to count the number of times each letter is present, with no regard to location of said letters, why would you expect `Test.s("test","here","testhere")` and `Test.s("test","here","tehstere")` to have different result, since they have exactly the same number of each letter? The stated goal and the code you wrote are entirely at cross purpose. Re-think what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java boolean result for mixed string value using an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55408239/java-boolean-result-for-mixed-string-value-using-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a different approach to your problem. Refer to the code comments for details.

Code:

```
public class Main2 {

    static int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(s("test", "now", "tesntow")); // true
        System.out.println(s("test", "here", "testhere")); // false
        System.out.println(s("test", "here", "tehstere")); // true
        System.out.println(s("test", "new", "tesntewword")); // false
    }

    public static boolean s(String one, String two, String three) {
        String combined = one + two; // combine the two words
        combined = combined.toLowerCase(); // convert to lowercase
        three = three.toLowerCase(); // convert to lowercase

        // check if it has the same length, if not then return false
        // check if it is the same, if it is then return false
        if (combined.length() != three.length() || combined.equals(three)) {
            return false;
        }

        // iterate through the combined words
        for (int i = 0; i < combined.length(); i++) {
            // declare and initialize a flag
            boolean flag = false;

            // check if the current letter of the combine word is in the third word
            flag = three.contains(combined.charAt(i) + ""); // just add empty string to make it a string (Brute force)
            if (!flag) {
                return false;
            }

            // remove the letter from the third word
            int j = three.indexOf(combined.charAt(i));
            three = three.substring(0, j) + three.substring(j);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
true
false
true
false
```

Comment: I see, i'll write down in my notes, that is smart, I didn't think of using length as to determine the extra false value, thank you. Srry to bother but one last question, when I test ran it, why does "cat", "dog", "dcaotg" return as false?

Comment: When I ran it on my end and it return as true. I don't know why it return as false on your end thou